# MvvmCross 4.1 upgrade issue IsFragmentCacheable not found

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, mvvmcross

Getting a compilation error after upgrade to mvvmcross 4.1 in Linker task:

`The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Boolean MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Attributes.MvxFragmentAttributeExtensionMethods::IsFragmentCacheable(System.Type)' (defined in 'MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Boolean MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Attributes.MvxFragmentAttributeExtensionMethods::IsFragmentCacheable(System.Type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception innerException, String message, Object[] args)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()`

What could be the reason for it? All referenced assemblies are updated to 4.1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should remove the `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging` package since this is included in `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4` now.

After that update your namespaces, and the app will work again!

Comment: Martijn00, I have a little dilemma.  I'm getting the exact same error message as the original poster.  I try to remove the Mvvmcross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging package, but the IDE says I can't because Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat relies on it.  I am using the AppCompat library, so I can't have that removed.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Scratch that, just updated my MvvmCross.Droid.Support.v7.AppCompat nuget package to 4.1.5 and it resolved my issue.  Thanks!