# Adding multiple parent activities for one fragment

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a **fragment** that needs to be accessible while the user is **logged in** and while the user is **logged out**. Hence I need **one fragment** to be used by **two activities**. I'm using **mvvmcross 4.1 with Xamarin and Monodroid** with the newly added multi parent feature for fragments. I'm not sure if I've implemented it right.

I **do not want to use a ViewPager** because of the adjacent screens that load while viewing a screen.

I get the `Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {za.co.app.something.example/examplepcl.droid.views.GetHelpView}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` error when I try navigating to the fragment that has two parent activities.

I've been looking at the sample project on GitHub: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples/Example.Droid

Please comment and tell me whether I should update my question with the code of my base classes and the viewModels.

**My fragment:**

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using ExamplePCL.Droid.ModalPopups;
using ExamplePCL.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Attributes;

namespace ExamplePCL.Droid.Views
{
    [MvxFragment(typeof(LoggedOutTabViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
    [MvxFragment(typeof(LoggedInTabViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
    [Register("examplepcl.droid.views.GetHelpView")]
    public class GetHelpView : BaseFragment<GetHelpViewModel>
    {
        protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.gethelp;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

**My Activities:**

Activity 1:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using ExamplePCL.ViewModels;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using ExamplePCL.Droid.Fragments;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using ExamplePCL.Droid.Interfaces;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging.Caching;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;

namespace ExamplePCL.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(
        Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
        WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize | SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden,
        Name = "examplepcl.droid.views.LoggedInTabView")]
    public class LoggedInTabView : BaseLoggedCachingFragmentActivity<LoggedInTabViewModel>, IDrawerActivity
    {
        TabLayout _globalNavTabLayout;
        int _previousTab;

        #region Activity LifeCycle Handling

        protected override int ContentLayoutId => Resource.Layout.loggedin_base_view;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            if (bundle == null)
                ViewModel.ShowMenu();

            // Setup tabs
            _globalNavTabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
            SetupTabLayout();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected -= GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabSelected -= GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected;
            base.OnPause();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected += GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabSelected += GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected;
            base.OnResume();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Menu and Toolbar Option Handling

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    DrawerLayout.OpenDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
                    return true;
            }
            return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Tab Layout

        void GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected(object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            int tabPosition = e.Tab.Position;

            SetTabPosition(tabPosition);
        }

        void GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected(object sender, TabLayout.TabReselectedEventArgs e)
        {
            int tabPosition = e.Tab.Position;

            SetTabPosition(tabPosition);
        }

        void SetupTabLayout()
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout_loggedin);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.icon_my_bill);

            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout_loggedin);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(1).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ico_my_products);

            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(2).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout_loggedin);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(2).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_launchpadimage);

            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(3).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout_loggedin);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(3).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ico_get_help);

            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(4).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout_loggedin);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(4).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ico_track);

            //Bring the TabLayout to the front so that it overlays the main content in the
            var tabLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_appbar_globalnav);
            tabLayout.BringToFront();

            SetTabPosition(2);
        }

        void SetTabPosition(int index)
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0:
                    ViewModel.ShowMyBillScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
                case 1: // My Products
                    ViewModel.ShowMyProductsScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
                case 3: // Help
                    ViewModel.ShowGetHelpScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
                case 4: // Tracks
                    ViewModel.ShowTrackScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
                case 2: // QuickLinks
                    ViewModel.ShowQuickLinksScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content.PM;
using ExamplePCL.ViewModels;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging.Caching;
using ExamplePCL.Droid.Fragments;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExamplePCL.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(
        Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
        Name = "examplepcl.droid.views.LoggedOutTabView")]
    public class LoggedOutTabView : BaseLoggedCachingFragmentActivity<LoggedOutTabViewModel>
    {
        TabLayout _globalNavTabLayout;
        int _previousTab;

        #region Activity LifeCycle Handling

        protected override int ContentLayoutId => Resource.Layout.loggedout_base_view;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            if (bundle == null)
                ViewModel.ShowMenu();

            // Setup tabs
            _globalNavTabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
            SetupTabLayout();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected -= GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabSelected -= GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected;

            base.OnPause();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected += GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabSelected += GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected;
            base.OnResume();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Tab Layout

        void GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected(object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabSelected -= GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected;
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected -= GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;

            int tabPosition = e.Tab.Position;

            SetTabPosition(tabPosition);

            _globalNavTabLayout.TabSelected += GlobalNavTabLayout_TabSelected;
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected += GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;
        }

        void GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected(object sender, TabLayout.TabReselectedEventArgs e)
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected -= GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;

            int tabPosition = e.Tab.Position;

            SetTabPosition(tabPosition);

            _globalNavTabLayout.TabReselected += GlobalNavTabLayout_TabReselected;
        }


        public void SetupTabLayout()
        {
            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(0).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ico_get_help);

            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(1).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(1).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ico_track);

            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(2).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(2).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_launchpadimage);

            _globalNavTabLayout.AddTab(_globalNavTabLayout.NewTab());
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(3).SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.tab_layout);
            _globalNavTabLayout.GetTabAt(3).CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.tab_icon).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.ico_lock);

            //Bring the TabLayout to the front so that it overlays the main content
            var tabLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linlay_appbar_globalnav);
            tabLayout.BringToFront();

            SetTabPosition(2);
        }

        async void SetTabPosition(int index)
        {
            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: // Get Help
                    ViewModel.ShowGetHelpScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
                case 1: // Track
                    ViewModel.ShowTrackScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
                case 2: // Quick Links
                    ViewModel.ShowQuickLinksScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
                case 3: // Login
                    ViewModel.ShowLoginScreenCommand.Execute();
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The issue seems to be with the way I'm using the library `MvvmCross.Droid.Shared.Attributes`. If I use just one attribute (`[MvxFragment(typeof(LoggedOutTabViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]`) I still get the same error.

However if I use the library `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging.Attributes` with just one attribute then I get no errors. But obviously I can't use that library as I need two attributes for multiple activities.

Comment: In this exact case it seems silly to have these two activities based on the fact that you are logged in or not. Why not have the ViewModel determine what to do based on that and just toggle visibility of available tabs?

Comment: THanks for the fast reply @cheesebaron!! I would of loved to have done it like that but I can't make too many changes to the viewmodels or the architecture for that matter because of the iOS version that has been completed and the android release is nearing in. Its sort of out of my control to make too many architectural changes :( so I'm looking for a solution to will leave me with minimal changes to make.

Comment: What does your `IDrawerActivity` implement? This `Interface` isn't implemented within your `LoggedOutTabView`.

Comment: That's because in the base class I'm checking which activity is using the base class and then I add a drawer if the activity is the LoggedInTabView. I could update the code to use an interface instead but I don't think that's the issue here. But I definitely would like to make use of the IDrawerActivty interface as it's a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging` package from your project, as it has been [depricated](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging/) as of Mvx 4.1.4 release. It now forms part of `MvvmCross.Droid.Shared` package, which you can get off  [nuget Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.Shared/). Having both packages installed has been shown to cause [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36789223/mvvmcross-4-1-upgrade-issue-isfragmentcacheable-not-found).

Comment: It took a lot of refactoring but removing the package `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging` did the trick. Thanks for your help, you saved me a lot of time!

Comment: MvvmCross.Droid.Shared was used until 5.1.1, need to change to MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than a solution but you could do this:

Instead of having one Fragment class called `GetHelpView`, create these three ->

```
GetHelpViewLoggedOut

GetHelpViewLoggedIn

GetHelpViewBase
```

GetHelpViewBase can contain all the common code between `GetHelpViewLoggedIn` and `GetHelpViewLoggedOut`and even reuse the same `ViewModel`

Not ideal, but could be a workaround.